# Discord.py воспроизведение музыки по url (python)

Tags: python, discord.py

Мне надо чтобы когда заходила определенная роль заходил бот и воспроизводил музыку(музыка url),
не совсем понял как это сделать из оригинальной документации
я понял как определить роль

```
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(usr, before, after):
    if ((before.channel and usr not in before.channel.members) or not before.channel) and\
        after.channel and usr in after.channel.members and\
        usr.guild.get_role(828681693954572288) in usr.roles:
```

бот понимает кто зашел но вот что делать дальше я не понимаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример реализации проигрывания аудио **с компьютера** из [этого вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53604339/how-do-i-make-my-discord-py-bot-play-mp3-in-voice-channel)

```
...
voice_channel = user.voice.voice_channel
channel = None
if voice_channel != None:
    channel = voice_channel.name
    vc = await client.join_voice_channel(voice_channel)
    player = vc.create_ffmpeg_player('music.mp3', after=lambda: print('done'))
    player.start()
    while not player.is_done():
         await asyncio.sleep(1)
    player.stop()
    await vc.disconnect()
```

Пример реализации **потоковой трансляции** аудио из [этого вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56060614/how-to-make-a-discord-bot-play-youtube-audio)

```
youtube_dl.utils.bug_reports_message = lambda: ''


ytdl_format_options = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'outtmpl': '%(extractor)s-%(id)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s',
    'restrictfilenames': True,
    'noplaylist': True,
    'nocheckcertificate': True,
    'ignoreerrors': False,
    'logtostderr': False,
    'quiet': True,
    'no_warnings': True,
    'default_search': 'auto',
    'source_address': '0.0.0.0' # bind to ipv4 since ipv6 addresses cause issues sometimes
}

ffmpeg_options = {
    'options': '-vn'
}

ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ytdl_format_options)

class YTDLSource(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer):
    def __init__(self, source, *, data, volume=0.5):
        super().__init__(source, volume)

        self.data = data

        self.title = data.get('title')
        self.url = data.get('url')

    @classmethod
    async def from_url(cls, url, *, loop=None, stream=False):
        loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
        data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url, download=not stream))

        if 'entries' in data:
            # take first item from a playlist
            data = data['entries'][0]

        filename = data['url'] if stream else ytdl.prepare_filename(data)
        return cls(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(filename, **ffmpeg_options), data=data)
```

Функция для бота:

```
@commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def play(self, ctx, *, url):
        print(url)
        server = ctx.message.guild
        voice_channel = server.voice_client

        async with ctx.typing():
            player = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=self.bot.loop)
            ctx.voice_channel.play(player, after=lambda e: print('Player error: %s' % e) if e else None)
        await ctx.send('Now playing: {}'.format(player.title))
```

Comment: но тут же фаил должен быть на пк правильно (а я хочу запускать ауди из инета)

Comment: @Marlin09 Спасибо за ваше ожидание. Переписал ответ.

Comment: Не парьтесь и используйте wavelink